# Heroku with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, heroku

Does Heroku support SQL Server? What should I write my SQL Server database connection string in order to make it run in Heroku?

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DatabaseConnection"
         connectionString="Data Source=Hp\HpLaptop;Initial Catalog=PracticeDB;Integrated Security=true"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: use heroku docker and install sql server image on a container then deploy it to heruko :)

Comment: Adding a database docker image is a bad idea. I asked a question to Heroku about support for sql server as the new version will run on linux and they told me you can do this but it is not designed for persistence in the containers so databases are not a great idea.
https://help.heroku.com/tickets/536833

Answer (score 9):

Heroku is agnostic about your choice of datastore but they do not offer SQL Server like they offer Postgres as an addon. If you've an external SQL Server database and the appropriate environment on Heroku then there is nothing stopping you from connecting to it.

To connect you would configure your adapter/driver in the same way you would traditionally for your framework of choice. Of course the credentials should be stored in the environment rather than committed to the repo.